# Excel - Need help in VLOOKUP function

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, lookup

I am an Excel beginner. Could anyone help me?

I am quite confused with this lookup function. Why is cell C6 the lookup value while D6+1 is the lookup row? When I tried to use D6 as lookup value and got wrong results. Why?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather unusual way to use HLOOKUP(). Usually the lookup row is a constant.

But in this case, the user wants to look up values in successive rows of the lookup table.  I can't tell you *why* they want to do that, but I'll explain how the formula is working.

Column D contains 1,2,3,4,5 so the lookup row index (row where the result is found) will be 2,3,4,5,6 as the formula is filled down.

The lookup value is always 2, except for the second to last row, where it is 1. So the HLOOKUP() will return the values in rows 2-6 of column F, except for the second to last row, where it uses 1 as the lookup value and returns 3 from column E.

You can't use D6 as the lookup row because that would be the first row.  HLOOKUP() finds the lookup value in the first row and then returns the corresponding value from a different row specified by the row index.

I hope this helps. Ask a question in the comments if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed explanation! I understand it now.